# Как в меню сделать ограничение на ввод больше 2 чисел?

Tags: c#, консоль

Меню создаю следующим образом:

```
string[] Menu = 
{
   "(1) Создать архив",
   "(2) Отправить отчет.",
   "(3) Удалить отчет.",
   "(4) Дополнительная функция"
};
int j = 0;
do
{
  for (var i = 0; i < Menu.Length; i++)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(Menu[i]);
  }
  Console.Write("Выберите нужную функцию: ");
  if (int.TryParse(ans, out j))
  {
     switch (j)
     {
        case 1: break;
        case 2: break;
        case 3: break;
        case 4: break;
        default: break;
     }
  }
}
while (j != 0);
```

---

Как ввести ограничение на ввод больше 2 чисел?

И не помешало бы запретить использование букв.

---

[**Пример**]

222 - Так не нужно

2 - так нужно =)

То есть больше 1 числа в длину нельзя было вводить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
public static string ReadLimited(int limit, bool denyLetter = true)
{
    var str = string.Empty;
    while (true)
    {
        var c = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;

        // Если нажали Enter.
        if (c == '\r')
        {
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            break;
        }

        // Если нажали Backspace.
        if (c == '\b')
        {
            if (str != "")
            {
                str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
        }
        else if (str.Length < limit)
        {
            // Если запрещен ввод букв.
            if (denyLetter)
            {
                var s = c.ToString();
                var isDigit = s.Any() && s.All(char.IsDigit);
                if (isDigit)
                {
                    Console.Write(c);
                    str += c;
                }       
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(c);
                str += c;
            }   
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

Использование:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = ReadLimited(2);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Что и хотел ) Спасибо

Comment: А можно дополнительно как-нибудь заблокировать другие цифры? Есть 4 пункта, и только чтобы можно было вводить `(1,2,3,4)`

Comment: @GooliveR в метод `ReadLimited` можно добавить дополнительный  параметр, в который передавать коллекцию запрещенных символов (букв, цифр) и перед тем как отображать введённый символ на консоли, проверять, что он не входит в список запрещенных.

Comment: Кстати очень странное поведение обнаружил, вроде бы сначала нормально работало, а потом началось выпендриваться. То есть если при запуске выбрать пункт, и нажать "Enter", ничего не происходит, но если ещё раз ввести пункт и нажать "Enter", то всё работает.

Comment: @GooliveR не совсем понял. У вас не осуществляется переход на новую строку при нажатии `Enter`?

Comment: Ну типо того, выбрал пункт, нажал "Enter" он перешёл на новую строку, но мой метод из блока `switch case` не сработал.

Comment: @GooliveR изменил код. Сделал что бы при нажатии на `Enter` был переход на новую строку. Покажите ваш код, который на данный момент есть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63709/discussion-between-gooliver-and-sp7).

Answer (score 1):

Вот как ещё можно было сделать:

```
int j;
char ans  = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
if (int.TryParse(ans.ToString(), out j))
```

После ввода цифры, консоль автоматически реагирует, что не даёт вводить в консоль больше **1**-го числа.